# What's the preferred way of having an object available everywhere in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, state, stateless, stateful

The project I'm working on requires me to have some objects, including an event manager, (read-only) configuration manager and plugin manager, that are available everywhere in the system.

I was using global variables for these, until someone (with a C++ background) kindly pointed out that "You're probably doing something wrong if you need global variables".
He suggested using a state object that's passed to all functions that need it.
So I did:

```
$state = new State();
$state->register('eventManager' , new EventManager());
$state->register('configManager', new ConfigManager());
$state->register('cacheManager' , new CacheManager());
$state->register('pluginManager', new PluginManager());

$state->get('pluginManager')->initialize($state);
```

While I can see the benefit of this method in more stateful languages, it seems kind of pointless to me in a (mostly?) stateless language like PHP, where the state is lost after the page is done loading.

Is there any benefit to passing a state object around in a (mostly) stateless language like PHP, does it hold any benefits over other approaches (i.e. a globals-based system) and are there better ways to handle this?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. You may want to find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: What you want is *dependency injection*, and your "state object" here is something like a first stab at a dependency injection container. Whether anything here has state or not is beside the point, it's all about *managing code relationships*. And that's useful in any and all languages.

Comment: Also, PHP is not "stateless". It is most often used in a web server to handle stateless requests; but can just as easily be used in a very "stateful" way instead.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I wasn't sure if it was suitable for SO, but based on other questions on here about whether or not globals are bad, I figured there'd be things that'd be considered "best practices" and hoped that'd be a good enough reason for a SO question.

Comment: @deceze Hmm I see, didn't know that term. Guess I got some new google-material then. Also I'm aware PHP isn't really stateless, but the way it's used here it might as well be. As it wasn't really relevant to the question if it's truely stateless or not I didn't go into detail and left it at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registry that you propose is still a global variable. And if you want to access a global variable (even if it is an object, although a global one), you are doing something wrong.

A proper application only has on phase where global state plays a role: When bootstrapping it. The request starting the script is global, any request data sent with it is global, and any configuration that affects the application and is stored in a file or some other appropriate storage is global.

The first phase should initialize some dependency injection that puts all the parts that make up the application together. That object graph would be created on demand when the processing of the request has decided which part of the code should be called to respond to the request.

Usually this decision is done inside a framework processing the request, and the dependency injection likely will be also done via a framework. Your own code would only accept either the values needed to operate, or the other objects that are needed.

For example, if your code would need a database, then you'd configure the database object to accept the URL and credentials for your database, and then you'd configure your reader object to accept that database object.

It would be the task of the dependency injection to either create only one single database object, or multiple of them. You don't have to use the outdated "singleton antipattern" because it has many drawbacks.

So in this scenario, there are some objects existing in the dependency injection part that are only created once and injected when needed. These objects do not enforce to be only created once, and they are not stored inside a globally accessible variable. However, something has to live in a global variable, but this is only the main framework object and probably the dependency injection container, and they are never shared into the remaining code as a global variable - so this is not harmful at all.

Comment: In this case, this is going to be the framework. It isn't very clear from the code, but I am not accessing $state as global variable atm, rather passing it as parameter like in the last line.  
I read up a bit on dependency injection, wouldn't that mean I'd end up with a lot of parameters for certain functions? I.e. functions that call other functions that have dependencies would get those same dependencies as well, right? Wouldn't that get very messy very quickly?

Comment: @SharkWipf - it very well could. There isn't a single solution to your question - sometimes, certain classes only require simple solutions like singletons; other times, solutions like Sven's suggestion are more appropriate. Most of today's frameworks provide their own "flavour" of how to do this exact thing, along with their own parlance and set of opinions to boot.

Comment: Marking this as accepted because it's the closest to what I ended up using and no new answers seem to be coming in.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is with **singletons**:

```
class ConfigManager {
    private static $instance = NULL;

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(self::$instance === NULL) {
            self::$instance = new ConfigManager();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct(){
         // Notice that this is private - only getInstance() can call this.
    }
}

// When you need it:
$config = ConfigManager::getInstance();
```

---

There are many different opinions on how to do what you're asking - and I myself don't think singletons are always the best way to do this, either. It really depends on your use-case.

That said, singletons are just one common pattern for a class whose instance is supposed to be accessible everywhere.

Comment: Really? Singletons? There are only two opinions on them: One says that this pattern is described in the ["Gang of Four" book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), so it is good (and it's likely the answer of assumed bad developers in interviews when asked about their knowledge of software patterns). The other says that the original authors of said book reversed their opinion later and declared it an antipattern that should be avoided.

Comment: @Sven - The question was, "What's the preferred way of having an object available everywhere in PHP?" - to which this is one of many valid answers. I'm not disagreeing with you - did I not also mention that I didn't think singletons are always best way to do this? For something like a simple global configuration class in a small application, this very well might be the best way to do it. For something larger in scope, probably not. You are welcome to post an alternative method, if you feel so inclined. :-)